# Generating new variable values by subset

Tags: r, merge, indexing, subset

I have a data set, and I am trying to create a new variable with random values that are associated with a particular subset.

For example, given the data frame:

```
data(iris)
iris=iris
```

I want another variable that associates each value of `iris$Species` with a random number (between 0 and 1). This can be accomplished in a circuitous fashion by creating a data frame:

```
df=data.frame(unique(iris$Species),runif(length(unique(iris$Species))))
```

And merging it with the original data frame:

```
iris=merge(iris,df,by.x="Species",by.y="unique.iris.Species.")
```

This accomplishes what I want, but it is inelegant. Furthermore, if I wanted to replicate this process many times over different variables this process would be burdensome. What I would hope for is some quick indexing method that would hopefully look something like:

```
iris$Species.unif=runif(length(unique(iris$Species)))[iris$Species]
```

Given that indexing in R is typically very slick, I expect there is some way of doing this that I am not aware of.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try by using levels:

```
iris <- iris
iris$species_unif <- iris$Species
levels(iris$species_unif ) <- runif(length(levels(iris$Species)))
```